# How to get a div with a particular class name

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote the following script to try to extract between the content from the `div` tag called `markers`

```
phone_category_data = requests.get(phone_category_url)
base_category_soup = soup(phone_category_data.content, "html.parser")
div_list = base_category_soup.find_all("div")
for div in div_list:
    if div["class"]:
        if div['class'][0] == 'makers':
            print div.text
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Does it find the wrong thing? Does it not find anything? Does it throw an error, and if so, what error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to check for class names when locating elements would be to use:

```
base_category_soup.find_all("div", class_="makers")
```

Or, using a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
base_category_soup.select("div.makers")
```

Note that since `class` is a *multi-valued attribute* and `BeautifulSoup` has a special handling for it, both of the approaches would check for any of the class values to be `makers`, e.g. all of the following would match:

```
<div class="makers"></div>
<div class="test makers"></div>
<div class="makers test"></div>
<div class="test1 makers test2"></div>
```